# res scope in nodejs and ending the response if password mismatches by express-validator

Tags: node.js, express

```
const { check, validationResult,body } = require('express-validator');
     router.post('/signup',[
         body('confirmpassword').custom((value, {req, res }) =>{
             if(value !== req.body.password) {
                 console.log(value)
                 console.log(res) // undefined
                 console.log(req) // printing my total req object including the data which i am passing in postman 
                 console.log("passworss didnot match")
                 return res.end("password and confirm password didinot match") // going to auth.signup controllel
                // throw  new Error ("passwords didnot match")

             }
         })
     ], auth.signUp);
```

1) In the above code when i console log the req i can see the total req  and data I  attached  in the postman

2) but when i  console log the res is printing undefined

3) can anyone explain me the res object , and when  it will be intilized in the nodejs and why it is printing undefined

4) how to end my res in mycode when passwords didn't match

5)In the above code in flowing to the auth.signup method even when my passwords are missmatched

Answer (score 0):

why do you need express-validator to do password match. Doesn't this work for you?

```
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.password !== req.body.confirmPassword) {
        // return error i.e return res.status(400).send('Password mismatch')
    }
    // do the signup and return your response i.e res.status(201).send(user);
});
```

Comment: Thanks 

could you clear my doubt about req and res scope and i want to learn express validation so i used? why do res is printing undefinded iinside my methhhod

Comment: What is the  [ .. ] section that you pass as second parameter to router.post doing? Is it acting as a middleware?

Comment: I think i got, i am getting custom value from the body and i think body will have only req  it will not have any res object so it is throwing undefined